# extract text file in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

i have small  doubt while extract text file data into sql server table using ssis tool.
Source data (text file)like:

```
id  ,   name    ,    address
  1   ,   abc     ,     chennai,tamilnadu
```

based on this source data i want  load same data into sql server table
 table data output like
   table name:test
  id     name       address
  1      abc         chennai,tamilnadu

please let me know where  done mi stick  while processing this data. first configure this text file that time header row delimiter `{CR}{LF}`.
column delimiter:,  after that i configure that file into  table test.then i ran package after that i got result
like below

```
id       name      address
1         abc      chennai
```

but i want load address columns chennai,tamil

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it appears that you are using comma as a delimiter, but you also have commas in your data.  You either need change the delimiter (to tab or something more unique) or you need to add a text qualifier.  A text qualifier, like a quote, would surround the data like this:

```
 "id"  ,   "name"    ,    "address"
  "1"   ,   "abc"     ,     "chennai,tamilnadu"
```

The comma inside the quotes would then be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, from [this article](http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/09/flat-files-with-too-many-delimiters/), that having the column affected by excess delimiters at the end could be made to work if the last column specifies its delimiter as {CR}{LF}.

Answer (score 0):

If address is your last column and your row delimiter is {CR}{LF} and column delimiter is , then as per your scenario address field will load chennai,tamilnadu not chennai into destination server. check your package once again.